# Haskell "not a visible field of constructor" error

Tags: haskell, constructor, algebraic-data-types

I'm getting an error I don't quite understand:

```
AnotherModule.hs:6:38:
    `something' is not a (visible) field of constructor `M.SomeType'

AnotherModule.hs:7:38:
    `somethingElse' is not a (visible) field of constructor `M.SomeType'
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error and how I might go about fixing it?

#### Main.hs

```
import qualified SomeModule as M
import qualified AnotherModule as A

main = print $ A.makeSomeType M.Constructor1
```

#### SomeModule.hs

```
module SomeModule (SomeType(..), AnotherType(..)) where

data SomeType = SomeType { something     :: [String]
                         , somethingElse :: [AnotherType]
                         } deriving (Show)
data AnotherType = Constructor1
                 | Constructor2
                 deriving (Show)
```

#### AnotherModule.hs

```
module AnotherModule (makeSomeType) where

import qualified SomeModule as M

makeSomeType :: M.AnotherType -> M.SomeType
makeSomeType something = M.SomeType { something     = []
                                    , somethingElse = [something]
                                    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`something` and `somethingElse` are basically functions defined in `SomeModule`. Try

```
makeSomeType something = M.SomeType { M.something     = []
                                    , M.somethingElse = [something]
                                    }
```